# Monitoring more than 20 stores with CLLocationManager inaccurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I'm building an app that notifies the user every time he passes a store of my client.

The problem is that it has more than 20 stores and CLLocationManager allows to monitor up to 20 stores at the same time.

So what I have done is finding the 20 closest stores to the user's current location but it's inaccurate for some reason.

Its seems like the locationManager monitors the regions correctly just the first time app runs.

Can someone look at my code and tell me if he sees soemthing wrong? Thanks!!

My code (scroll to see all of it):

```
-(void)sortClosestStores
{
    [self.allStores sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    CLLocation *location1=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.longitude];
    CLLocation *location2=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.longitude];

    float dist1 =[location1 distanceFromLocation:self.userLocation];
    float dist2 = [location2 distanceFromLocation:self.userLocation];
    if (dist1 == dist2) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if (dist1 < dist2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];

    if (self.twentyClosestStores==nil) {
    self.twentyClosestStores=[NSMutableArray array];
    }

    if (self.previousTwentyStores==nil) {
        self.previousTwentyStores=[NSMutableArray array];
    }
    self.previousTwentyStores=self.twentyClosestStores;

    NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        [self.twentyClosestStores addObject:[self.allStores objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    Store *nearest=[self.twentyClosestStores firstObject];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    self.userLocation=self.locationManager.location;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered");
}

-(void)stopMonitoringStores
{
    for (Store *currentStore in self.twentyClosestStores) {
        CLCircularRegion *region=[currentStore createCircularRegion];
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (self.allStores.count>=1171) {
         [self sortClosestStores];
    }
     if (self.previousTwentyStores!=nil||self.previousTwentyStores.count==0) {
         [self stopMonitoringStores];
     }
[self startMonitoringClosestStores];
}

-(void)startMonitoringClosestStores
{
    [self stopMonitoringStores];

    if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLCircularRegion class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Monitoring is not available for CLCircularRegion class");
    }

    for (Store *currentStore in self.twentyClosestStores) {
        CLCircularRegion *region=[currentStore createCircularRegion];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}
```

Can you see something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I remember that some time ago there was possibility to observing up to 20 regions, maybe that limitation is still valid(?)

Comment: When you call `stopMonitoringStores` you have already replaced the old stores in `twentyCloestStores` with the new closest stores, so the stop monitoring will be for the wrong regions.  You need to keep a record of the currently monitored regions and use that to stop monitoring

Comment: @Paulw11 So can I call in at the start of `sortClosestStores`?

Comment: It would be better to store in a completely different array or perhaps even persist the information in a store like CoreData so that you can know which regions are being monitored between app restarts

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried to do what you suggested, but still the same problem, I've updated the code (as you see I don't need to save it with CoreData because I'm creating the object when the app opens even in the background). It looks like twentyClosestStores is not up-to-date after the user exits a region (the stores are the closest stores from the start and not being updated). Can you please take a look at the new code? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to do the opposite: search for the stores less than 5km from user location and monitor for these? If user location changes for more than 1km, refresh nearby stores. Ofc digits are just an example. This way seems less heavy-duty for the CPU.

Comment: @Vive I don't think it's too-heavy for the CPU, I've tried to do that with 5 closest stores and even with one and it's the same problem. I do think that it's something wrong with the code, but I can't get on it.

Comment: I found the solution! I forgot to empty "twentyClosestStores" array

Comment: I don't claim it doesn't work because of CPU usage (because obviously it can't be the problem xD). It's not an answer, it's a suggestion. It isn't connected with the problem "why it does not work", but it should rather sound like "by the way you can improve that thing".